# com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Error code: 402620388

Tags: ios, xcode, device

not able to install and run application
keep getting:

```
Unable to install <AppName>
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
User Info: {
  DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-09-27 07:21:52 +0000";
  IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
```

already tried - restart PC & device, clear build, clean derived data Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after spending around three hours in this issue, it turn out that problem was with framework, it was "Embed Without Signing" instead of "Embed & Sign".

found similar issue from Apple developer [forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/692755):

> Solution to issue: Framework in Target (App) was set to "Embed Without
> Signing" which worked prior to Xcode 13, changed to "Embed & Sign"

Comment: Upvoted because this was exactly what resolved the issue for me as well

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case what helped was changing it to "Do not embed".
XCode version: 14.3
iPhone version: 15.7.5